# How do you sort only the first column in a csv file and not affect any of the other columns while doing so using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, sorting

**i am working on a table(csv file) where it has the following data:**

```
roll_no,student_name,grade,email_id  
1,Aarav Gosalia,Grade 11,aarav.gosalia@flag.org.in  
2,Aarav Rawal,Grade 11,aarav.rawal@flag.org.in  
3,Abizar Chitalwala,Grade 11,abizar.chitalwala@flag.org.in  
4,Ahad Motorwala,Grade 11,ahad.motorwala@flag.org.in  
5,Armaan Adenwala,Grade 11,armaan.adenwala@flag.org.in  
6,Aryan Shah,Grade 11,aryan.shah@flag.org.in  
7,Baasit Motorwala,Grade 11,baasit.motorwala@flag.org.in  
16,Caroline Walker,Grade 11,caroline.walker@flag.org.in  
8,Darsshan Kavedia,Grade 11,darsshan.kavedia@flag.org.in  
9,Devanshi Rajgharia,Grade 11,devanshi.rajgharia@flag.org.in  
10,Dhruv Jain,Grade 11,dhruv.jain@flag.org.in  
11,Eisa Patel,Grade 11,eisa.patel@flag.org.in  
12,Esha Khimawat,Grade 11,esha.khimawat@flag.org.in  
13,Fatima Unwala,Grade 11,fatima.unwala@flag.org.in  
14,Hamza Erfan,Grade 11,hamza.erfan@flag.org.in  
15,Harsh Gosar,Grade 11,harsh.gosar@flag.org.in
```

so as you can see all of the names are sorted but the roll number of caroline walker is 16. so i want a way to sort only the roll numbers and not affect any of the other columns while doing so.
**I want the final table to look like this:**

```
roll_no,student_name,grade,email_id   
1,Aarav Gosalia,Grade 11,aarav.gosalia@flag.org.in  
2,Aarav Rawal,Grade 11,aarav.rawal@flag.org.in  
3,Abizar Chitalwala,Grade 11,abizar.chitalwala@flag.org.in  
4,Ahad Motorwala,Grade 11,ahad.motorwala@flag.org.in  
5,Armaan Adenwala,Grade 11,armaan.adenwala@flag.org.in  
6,Aryan Shah,Grade 11,aryan.shah@flag.org.in  
7,Baasit Motorwala,Grade 11,baasit.motorwala@flag.org.in  
8,Caroline Walker,Grade 11,caroline.walker@flag.org.in  
9,Darsshan Kavedia,Grade 11,darsshan.kavedia@flag.org.in  
10,Devanshi Rajgharia,Grade 11,devanshi.rajgharia@flag.org.in  
11,Dhruv Jain,Grade 11,dhruv.jain@flag.org.in  
12,Eisa Patel,Grade 11,eisa.patel@flag.org.in  
13,Esha Khimawat,Grade 11,esha.khimawat@flag.org.in  
14,Fatima Unwala,Grade 11,fatima.unwala@flag.org.in  
15,Hamza Erfan,Grade 11,hamza.erfan@flag.org.in  
16,Harsh Gosar,Grade 11,harsh.gosar@flag.org.in
```

Please help me and keep in mind that i am yet a beginner in python.

Comment: Have you managed to look at the `csv` module - specifically `csv.DictReader` and do you know of the `sorted` function? eg: how far along are you - do you know how to open a file and read it into memory etc... or at you literally sitting at your keyboard just with a file and have no idea where to start...?

Answer (score 0):

just use pandas. `df['roll_no'] = range(1:len(df))`

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` is one way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.sort_values(by='roll_no')
df.to_csv('file.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,3,2,7],
                   'name': ['M', 'r', 'd', 'd']})
df['id'] =  list(df['id'].sort_values())
df
```

Result:

```
    id  name
0   1   M
1   2   r
2   3   d
3   7   d
```